# Using v.voronoi.skeleton in Qgis 3.43 with Grass8

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, voronoi-thiessen, skeleton

In previous QGIS-versions that used Grass7 I designed a model that used v.voronoi.skeleton. But with the upgrade to 3.43, and Grass8, this model will not work anymore. It complaints that grass7:v.voronoi.skeleton is no longer available. When trying to find the equivalent module in grass8 I fail to do so. I find references to running v.voronoi -s in command line, but no function i qgis.

Is there a simple way of solving this? I have tried to look at other skeleton-plugins but can not find anyone that works as a replacement to the v.voronoi.skeleton. Is it possible to install an older grass7 and use that with a newer QGIS?

Comment: I also asked on the GRASS-side and they said nothing changed between grass7 & 8 for this function. The advice was to ask qgis-developers what happened with the wrapper that used to exist in qgis. Is this the right place to Adress that question?

Comment: Not really. You might get some info here, or perhaps a workaround, but if it's indeed an issue in QGIS, then you (and everyone) are better off if you bring it to the QGIS devs' attention. See [https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/index.html](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/index.html)

Comment: Installing an older GRASS is possible, but I don't think that will help: QGIS will not "see" it. Why not just run the module directly in GRASS? If you want to go this route, post back and we'll walk you thru.